# Closing a pop-up window after writing file to response

Tags: c#, asp.net, response

In my code, I am using JavaScript to fire off an `window.open()` event on an ASPX page. I´m outputting a file in the `Page_Load()` event of this page:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\";");
outputStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
outputStream.Flush();
outputStream.Close();
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```

Afterwards i want to close this popup window. But because I have changed my response type, I cant execute `window.close()` in JavaScript. It will just get appended to the file being given to the users. This thread is the most suitable source i found to solve my problem:

[Closing window after export to excel](http://forums.asp.net/t/1186371.aspx?PageIndex=1)

But the given answers dont help me, so i am basically stuck. I dont want to tell the user to close the window manually. Do you know how to achieve what i aim for?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload files form the AJAX page. What you need to do is in the code behind add the ID of the control, to the Update Panel Post back trigger, which requires a postback. If the control is on the same page, you will not have any issues.

However if you use a User control that has a button or another webcontrol that requires a postback, you will have to expose the ID of this control via a public property of the USer control and have the containing page retrieve this ID and add it as a post back trigger.

Comment: That would be fine, but I'm not making use of the standard asp.net UpdatePanel.

Answer (score 0):

One option I've used in the past was firing the download request into a hidden iframe instead of the popup window, via a bit of javascript:

```
var Utils = Utils || {};
Utils.download = function(url) {
    var iframe = $("<iframe/>").hide().appendTo("body").load(function() {
        iframe.remove();
    }).attr("src", url);
};
```

That way you don't need to worry about any visible popup windows. Only downside is that if the file download fails, the user gets no hint at all what went wrong (whereas in your case they'd still have the popup window with the error message intact). To work around this problem, instead of returning the file, return a page containing some javascript that fires an alert of some sort on load to inform the user of the error.

Also note, from memory, the `iframe.remove()` call on load of the iframe doesn't work in all (any?) browsers, but at the end of the day it doesn't really matter anyway since at worst you're just ending up with a bunch of empty iframes attached to the end of the dom which shouldn't cause any problems (and you could always keep reusing the same one rather than creating new ones if it was a problem).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the point. To close the popup you must use the script mananger to do this, given that you are firing the `Upload` from the `UpdatePanel`. So register the script like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanelObject, UpdatePanelObject.GetType(), "scripname","your  script here", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you firing the download of the file via a simple

```
<a href="/path/to/your/page.aspx" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

This will call your page in a different window, the download will start and the page should automatically close.

Comment: Firefox... Just Firefox. It doesn't close download windows.